# CppUnit for unit-testing executables or ELFs?

Tags: unit-testing, executable, elf, cppunit

I have only used UnitTest++ with my previous project. But I never had the misfortune to test executables/ELFs. I remember that someone on stackoverflow posted something about CppUnit but cannot remember anymore.

**MY PROBLEM**

I want to use CppUnit for testing .exe and ELFs. Unit testing is what I think would be the solution.

**WHAT I THINK WOULD BE HELPFUL**

...I HAVE NO CLUE....I simply have not done any .exe/ELF unit-testing in my life. I have done agile-ish thing before buting this is a whole new ball game. I would appreciate anybody has got any experience in this.

Answer (score 0):

CppUnit is a framework for automated unit testing, not automated system testing.

System testing is just what its name implies.  It's all about testing all the code modules together as a complete system from a user's point of view.  Automated system testing is when you exercise your entire system from a test harness, providing it with specific user inputs and testing that the behaviors and outputs function as expected.

Unit testing is all about testing the smallest possible unit of code from a code point of view, providing it with entry conditions and asserting the exit conditions are properly met.  At its best, one unit test should exercise one path through a method on a public interface of a class, free of external dependencies on hard-to-provide resources like databases or services.  Unit testing is a developer tool for testing that a module does all the things exactly how it is supposed to do them.  It's a very detailed approach to testing, and not really something you would think about from an executable point of view.

All that said, code that you intend to test with CppUnit still needs to be linked in order to be executed.  What we do is write our production code in one project, and our test code in a separate project.  When we build, the production code project builds first, compiling the production .CPP files into .OBJ files, and then linking them into PROD.DLL or PROD.EXE (whatever the project is intended to produce.)  We build the test project next, compiling the test .CPP files into .OBJ files.  The test project then links both the test .OBJ files with the immediately previously compiled production .OBJ files into a TEST.EXE. This way our tests are linked with the same .OBJ files that were used to create the actual production code. We then execute TEST.EXE and insure the tests reveal no errors before the build completes.

Comment: `@JohnDeters` I have a problem where some of my customer data come in .EXE, .OBJ, and ELF formats. I need to link them with my in-house modules and complete integration for the final product. At this moment, I have no documented/established mean of testing those customer data. This is why I posted the question. What you are telling me is something that I already do! And the key issue is that  we have NO access to the source code. This is why it is even more challenging. I hope you get the problem!

Comment: @hagubear, I'm assuming their code constitutes an API that your code must integrate with, and you want to ensure they are holding up their end of the contract. You could do this with CppUnit the same way you'd test your own code. Write a test case to invoke their API, and assert their results. Link your test code with their .OBJ files, producing a TEST.EXE. You'll have issues if they have hidden dependencies, as you'll have to know to set those up at the start of a test.  You'll be blackbox testing with a whitebox tool, but it can still work.